# Maximum Absolute difference between the sum of array variables

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There are N numbers. 
a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],....,a[N]

There are two phases:-

Phase 1:- find the sum of elements in the array from a[i] to a[j].

Phase 2:- find the sum of elements in the array from a[m] to a[n].

1 ≤ i ≤ j < m ≤ n ≤ N.

2 ≤ N ≤ 10000

-10^9 <= a[N] <= 10^9.

I have to calculate the total value of that is determined by the absolute difference between the values obtained in the two phases and this total value should be maximized.

for e.g.,

N=4
1 1 -1 -1

i = 1, j = 2, k = 3, l = 4.
The maximum total value hence obtained is | ( ( −1 ) + ( −1 ) ) − ( 1 + 1 ) | = 4 .

This is the question which I am trying to slove, I am a newbie, I dont know how to solve this question, Please guide me which algorithm to be used.How to find i,j,m and n for the condition.

Comment: Hate to ask, but what did you try? What are you specifically having issues with?

Comment: @nneonneo: i dont know how to solve this problem, I dont know which algorithm to be used, I have never solved this type of problem before,I am looing this question from the last day and I didnt get any logic to solve this.Kindly suggest me the algo, for this I ll be very obliged to you

Comment: Are you stuck on phase 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: @Patashu Phase 1 and Phase 2, how to decide for i and j or m and n such that sum will be maximum. :(

Comment: @alankrita You should rephrase the question so that it's clearer that you're trying to find i, j, m, n SUCH THAT the sum of elements... etc etc. In particular: "Obviously, I want to maximize this total value." This is not obvious, there's no reason why except that it's part of the problem description and you forgot to include it.

Comment: Are the values of i,j,m,n given, or are they what is to be found?  Please answer by editing the question, instead of replying in a comment.

Comment: @Patashu sorry for inconvenience, I have edited the question

Comment: @jwpat7 sorry i,j,m and n are not given :(

Comment: The question is very poorly phrased. It is not clear that the result of each phase is a *collection* of values. Furthermore, the values in phase 2 are dependent on the choice of j in phase 1, so it is not simply the maximum difference between the two phases. Finally, your example violates the constraint. Your example array contains negative numbers, which is not allowed by the problem statement.

Comment: this question is part of the codechef contest: http://www.codechef.com/JUNE13/problems/DELISH
An editorial will be put up after the contest, until then I recommend you solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @RaymondChen 10^(-9)<=a[N]<=10^9 so example is right.and yes the value of phase 2 is dependent on the value of j.

Comment: @robertking I am not asking for any solution :( please suggest me the algo to be used :(

Comment: In your example, a[4] = -1, but -1 is not between 10^(-9) and 10^9.

Comment: @Raymond Chen It seems that it is a typo and it should say -10^9 to 10^9. Otherwise, the problem is trivial (try the subarray of all elements minus the last vs the last, the sub array of all elements minus the last two vs the second last... etc, and then try pulling away from the start instead of from the end, and in O(n) you have tried all possible answers)

Comment: @RaymondChen sorry my mistake again :( it is -10^9.

Comment: Were you planning on sharing your contest credit with SO? Not doing so would be dishonest. On the other hand, doing so would be confessing to breaking the contest rules: "Discussing CodeChef’s problems or any aspect of problem, on any other platform on web, on identification, could lead to disabling of respective account and banning from the community."

Comment: @RaymondChen no i dont want to know solutoin, just the data structure name, ok i will not ask any more on this and will wait for editorials, I am not able to solve all questions this time but I will sure solve all questions one day and learn from the editorials

Comment: What part of "any aspect of problem" don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

as -10^9 <= a[N] <= 10^9 in float, use heap to avoid **loss of accuracy**.

If you don't know what is heap and its operation, you can find them on most algorithm books and webs.

here is pseudo-code,and I supposed i,j,m,n are given:

```
build a[i...j] to a max-heap heap1;
build a[m...n] to a min-heap heap2;
size1 = j-i+1;
size2 = n-m+1;
while(size1>1) {
    n1 = extractmax();
    n2 = extractmax();
    temp = n1+n2;
    insert(heap1,temp)
}
//do the same thing to heap2,but use extractmin() instead of extractmax()

result = abs(a[i])+a[m];
```

If i,j,m,n aren't given,find them by partition,which is a typical part of quick sort.

For example

```
a[0] = 0;
i=j=0;//a[0] is useless, and 1 ≤ i ≤ j < m ≤ n ≤ N
m=n=N;
if(a[N]<=0)
    temp = a[N];
a[N] = -1;
//pre: a[i...j] is non-positive
       a[m...n] is non-negetive

while(j<=m+1){
    while(a[j+1]<=0)
        j++;
    while(a[m-1]>=0)
        m--;
    if(j+1>m)
        break;
    swap(a[j+1],a[m-1]);
    j++;m--;
}
if(temp<=0) { //insert a[N] back
    a[N] = a[m];
    a[m] = temp;
    j = m;
    m++;
}

//then you will have checked all elements
//and make sure that non-positive elements are consecutive
//so as to non-negative elements
//now you have i,j,m,n to run pseudo-code at the beginning.
//although i,j may be not more than 0,it depends on the data in your array.
```